# emacs org-mode: table <td> style

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

The default HTML table exported from org-mode has this style:

```
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" rules="groups" frame="hsides">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">ID</th>
<th scope="col">First Name</th>
<th scope="col">Last Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Tom</td>
<td>Cruise</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Arnold</td>
<td>Schwarzenegger</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Sylvester</td>
<td>Stallone</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way to make it more compact to be like this:

```
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" rules="groups" frame="hsides">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">ID</th>
<th scope="col">First Name</th>
<th scope="col">Last Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Tom</td><td>Cruise</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Arnold</td><td>Schwarzenegger</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Sylvester</td><td>Stallone</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Since I have a very large size of table, the html file exported by the org-mode is simply too long all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex-replace on the html buffer does the job:

```
(defun compactify-html-table ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "<\\(/?t[rd]\\)>\n<\\(/?t[rd]\\)>" nil t)
    (replace-match "<\\1><\\2>"))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\n\n" nil t)
    (replace-match "\n")))
```

#### UPD: how to apply to all open html buffers:

```
(defun compactify-all-html-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc
   (lambda(b)
     (with-current-buffer b
       (when (eq major-mode 'html-mode)
         (compactify-html-table))))
   (buffer-list)))
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the export as a default setting in org-mode? I have about 530 HTML buffers. It would not be pleasant to change them one by one after the HTML exports. Thanks.

Comment: This is magical! Fewer lines than the awk & sed scripts I wrote to achieve the same effect! I have no idea why Carsten Dominik does not make the org-table export for HTML more compact, leaving users to take this extra step to complete the job. If org-mode can export plain, compact tables in one go, it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to tidy'fy the HTML output. With different parameters, you can get a more compact (and for sure, more consistent) presentation.